# Flutter - represent fractions

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to represent fractions this way in Flutter?

[image]

I tried some packages like `pie_chart` but I didn't get the expected result.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this package! It has a bunch of helpful graphs/charts.

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts